# node mysql if select gets results, return the results, else do a different select and return those results

Tags: mysql, node-mysql

I have 2 statements that work fine alone when talking to MySQL db. Both stored in variables like aSQL and bSQL.

So i'm trying to do the following where i return aSQL if any records from the query exist, else return the results from bSQL.

```
let sql = `
IF (${aSQL}) THEN
BEGIN
    ${aSQL};
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    ${bSQL};
END;
END IF;
`
```

I also tried the following from [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121213/sql-if-select-query-is-null-then-do-another-query) (replaced WHERE with AND because my query already has a WHERE):

```
let sql = `
with temp as (${aSQL})
select * from temp
union all
${bSQL} AND (select count(*) from  temp) =0
`
```

And even:

```
let sql = `SELECT IF(EXISTS(${aSQL}), 1, 0) ELSE ${bSQL}`
```

No mater what, i get `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near`.

But if i simply do `connection.query(aSQL)` or `connection.query(bSQL)` it works.

**How do you do this in a single query without permanently storing a procedure in the db?**

Note for non-js devs `` sql = `${aSQL}` `` is just a template and inputs full string value of var `aSQL` that might be equal to `SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE id=60 AND other=foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Found the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27366284/1628984):

```
let sql = `${aSQL} UNION ALL ${bSQL} AND NOT EXISTS (${aSQL})`
```

Where `aSQL` and `bSQL` look similar to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE id=60 AND other=foo
SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE id=47 AND other=bar
```

Answer (score 0):

just wait for result, and if result is empty, execute next query:

```
connection.query(aSQL, function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err || result == 0 || result.length == 0) {
      connection.query(bSQL, function(err, result, fields){console.log(result)});
    }else {
      console.log(result)
    }    
 });
```

Comment: I realize that's possible. My question was to find out how to do it in single query.

Comment: It returns `ER_OPERAND_COLUMNS: Operand should contain 1 column(s)` If i remove the extra `()` it returns same as my original results. I think all `IF` statements might require Stored Procedure